# Accessing list entries after spitting. Should be simple but I can't get this to work?

Tags: python, string, list, element

I'm opening a tab delimited file and for each line, I'm splitting elements into a list. I can access the first element in the list list[0], but trying to access subsequent elements isn't working.

Code to return first element on each line.. This works as expected

```
with open(fileX) as GFF_in:

   for line in GFF_in:

       list = line.split('\t')

print list[0]
```

but trying to access any of the other 6 elements with;

```
>>>print list[1] #2nd element

>>>print list[4] #5th element
```

throws the error "IndexError: list index out of range"

This is such super basic code... I cannot fathom why this isn't working!!? It's no different to manually assigning items to a list and printing them, ie;

```
>>> food = 'bread', 'chicken', 'the_other_white_meat'

>>> print food[2]

>>> the_other_white_meat
```

When I print the first element, it is definitely the first item on each line and if I print the whole list, all the elements are there for each line... Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong as I've been stuck on this for ages :/

Thanks

Mat.

Comment: The error clearly suggests that there are not enough items in list.

Comment: Can you show us the list output, as you claim that it contains all elements.

Comment: Start by not shadowing the builtin `list` with your variable

Comment: Ok, first apology is for the confusion.. I intended to clean up the code so it would be more obvious and using 'list' wasn't a great idea :/

Second apology.. I have realised what the snafu was. The file I'm parsing has a single entry header.
Gah.. I need coffee..

Thanks for taking the time to answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual reason is that the file ends with an empty line. It's easy to defend against this

```
for line in GFF_in:
    if not line:  # ignore empty lines
        break
    list_without_meaningful_name = line.split('\t')
    ...
```

or

```
for line in GFF_in:
    if not line:  # ignore empty lines
        break
    list_without_meaningful_name = line.split('\t')
    if len(list_without_meaningful_name) < 6:
        # uh oh
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your example gnibbler

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you wanted to do something like this:

```
>>> food = 'bread', 'chicken', 'the_other_white_meat'
>>> lis = [y for x in food for y in x.split('_')]
>>> lis
['bread', 'chicken', 'the', 'other', 'white', 'meat']
>>> lis[1]
'chicken'
>>> lis[5]
'meat'
```